# how add input field "address" to shipping calculator?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

i have problems with the shipping-calculator form.

I would like to add an address field, and when updating the user's address is changed.

I currently have this code.

```
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shipping_calculator' ); ?>

<form class="woocommerce-shipping-calculator" action="<?php echo esc_url( wc_get_cart_url() ); ?>" method="post">

    <?php printf( '<a href="#" class="shipping-calculator-button">%s</a>', esc_html( ! empty( $button_text ) ? $button_text : __( 'Calculate shipping', 'woocommerce' ) ) ); ?>

    <section class="shipping-calculator-form" style="display:none;">

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_country', true ) ) : ?>
            <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_country_field">
                <select name="calc_shipping_country" id="calc_shipping_country" class="country_to_state country_select" rel="calc_shipping_state">
                    <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Select a country / region&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
                    <?php
                    foreach ( WC()->countries->get_shipping_countries() as $key => $value ) {
                        echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $key ) . '"' . selected( WC()->customer->get_shipping_country(), esc_attr( $key ), false ) . '>' . esc_html( $value ) . '</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_state', true ) ) : ?>
            <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_state_field">
                <?php
                $current_cc = WC()->customer->get_shipping_country();
                $current_r  = WC()->customer->get_shipping_state();
                $states     = WC()->countries->get_states( $current_cc );

                if ( is_array( $states ) && empty( $states ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <input type="hidden" name="calc_shipping_state" id="calc_shipping_state" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'State / County', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
                    <?php
                } elseif ( is_array( $states ) ) {
                    ?>
                    <span>
                        <select name="calc_shipping_state" class="state_select" id="calc_shipping_state" data-placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'State / County', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
                            <option value=""><?php esc_html_e( 'Select an option&hellip;', 'woocommerce' ); ?></option>
                            <?php
                            foreach ( $states as $ckey => $cvalue ) {
                                echo '<option value="' . esc_attr( $ckey ) . '" ' . selected( $current_r, $ckey, false ) . '>' . esc_html( $cvalue ) . '</option>';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </span>
                    <?php
                } else {
                    ?>
                    <input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $current_r ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'State / County', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_state" id="calc_shipping_state" />
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_city', true ) ) : ?>
            <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_city_field">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_city() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'City', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_city" id="calc_shipping_city" />
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_shipping_calculator_enable_postcode', true ) ) : ?>
            <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="calc_shipping_postcode_field">
                <input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_postcode() ); ?>" placeholder="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Postcode / ZIP', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" name="calc_shipping_postcode" id="calc_shipping_postcode" />
            </p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        
        <!-- Start New Field -->
        <p class="form-row form-row-wide" id="shipping_address_field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text" value="<?php echo esc_attr( WC()->customer->get_shipping_address() ); ?>" id="shipping_address_field" name="shipping_address_field" placeholder="Ingrese su nueva dirección">
        </p>
        <!-- End New Field -->

        <p><button type="submit" name="calc_shipping" value="1" class="button"><?php esc_html_e( 'Update', 'woocommerce' ); ?></button></p>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'woocommerce-shipping-calculator', 'woocommerce-shipping-calculator-nonce' ); ?>
    </section>
</form>

<?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shipping_calculator' ); ?>
```

I was able to add the address field but I can't get it to work, How can I update the user's address from shipping calculator? Shipping is free, I just want to update the address.